# What is location for standard Apache Error Document for 404?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am working on customizing various error codes for apache and I know the way to do it. (By adding new pages and referencing them in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf against the various error codes.

My question here is - where does the standard error message for apache come from? For example if I run my local apache and try to browse a non existing URL, I get following error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /not_found was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

My httpd.conf does not have any ErrorDocument overrides. So this is standard apache error. When I grep, I don't find any file containing these texts.

So does that mean this is coming from an apache module?

Comment: be pragmatic. `grep -r ....`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The error comes from "c" file and apache does not have an default error html as I thought initially. Httpd source can be http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi.

Refer to "src\main\http_protocol.c" file and below is code that throws 404 exception with the given message.

```
case NOT_FOUND:
        ap_rvputs(r, "The requested URL ",
              ap_escape_html(r->pool, r->uri),
              " was not found on this server.<P>\n", NULL);
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its probably under `/usr/share/apache2`. On my system the file is `/usr/share/apache2/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var`. Maybe your grepping didn't find it because it is a type-map file (see [these](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#multi-lang) [pages](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) for details).

Comment: Tried that. Renaming/Removing this file and reloading apache still produces same html error doc I mentioned in the question. Please note, my httpd.conf does not have any error overrides right now.

Comment: Just to add - if I override the error document in httpd/conf and give an non-existent html reference as below

ErrorDocument 404 /non-existing.html

then also I get same Not Found error with another line "Additionally /non-existing.html not found"

Comment: @user1401472 I guess Apache also has a hard-coded default built in for cases where that file is not found. If there's more you want to know, you should have put it in your original question.

Comment: I do not want to know more than what I mentioned in the question. I just wanted to let you know that I tried what you mentioned and that did not help.

Comment: @user1401472 I did not mention any action.

Comment: The documents stored in this `/error` subdirectory (such as `HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var` etc.) relate to the multi-language (content negotiated) error documents. These are not the "built-in" Apache error responses and are not enabled by default. To enable this you must explicitly include `httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf` from the main server config/vHost. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#multi-lang

Answer (score 1):

The location of Apache 2.4 standard error messages is inside the executable. You can easily find them if you peek inside the executable with some hex editor.